# Speed up search using dispatch_async?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to speed up my app search , it get lags when there is a lot of data.

so i'm trying to split search **Predicate** on **UI** by using `dispatch_async` not `dispatch_sync` cause no different if I use it.

The problem is when i use `dispatch_async`, the app crash sometimes because `[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index "17" beyond bounds`.

I now this happened because lets say the first one still work and reload the tableView and continue search will change the array size depend on result so in this case "CRASH" :(

this is my code:

```
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        searchArray = [PublicMeathods searchInArray:searchText array:allData];
    } );

    if(currentViewStyle==listViewStyle){
        [mytable reloadData];
    }
```

and i've tried this :

```
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        NSArray *tmpArray = [PublicMeathods searchInArray:searchText array:allData];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            searchArray = tmpArray;
            [mytable reloadData];
        });
    });
```

but in this case the lags still there.

**Update -1- :**

The search Predicate takes just 2ms :) after hard work :)
but the keyboard still lags when the user searches, so the only thing I do after get result is reload table "change in UI" this what I think make it lags,

So what I search for split this two operation "typing on keyboard &  refresh UI".

**Update -2- :**

@matehat  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16879900/1658442

and

@TomSwift https://stackoverflow.com/a/16866049/1658442

**answers work like a charm :)**

Comment: if your search only takes 2ms, then the lag you're witnessing is due to your reloadData call. Looks at your tableview datasource&delegate for slowness.

Comment: how much items are there in allData and on average in tmpArray?

Comment: I would much more prefer a NSThread, and NSNotification.

Comment: @ShaneHsu could you explain why? What's wrong with GCD?

Comment: @AndreyChevozerov Cleaner, more straightforward code. Now there's nothing wrong with GCD, you can, of course use GCD with NSNotification, I just think that nesting these GCD calls might be problematic.

Comment: I also support what @escrafford said. If the search process only takes 2ms, then the problem isn't the search process, it's the UI update. If you can't change anything in the UI loading logic, try to change the frequency you refresh your data. For example, only perform the search process every 2 or 3 characters entered in the text field, or wait for a second or two after the user stops entering data.

Comment: you should profile this to really know where the slowdown is

Comment: also, I have some code you might find helpful if using Instrument's CPU sampler isn't helping https://github.com/nielsbot/Profiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution might be to voluntarily induce a delay between searches to let the user type and let the search be performed asynchronously. Here's how:

First make sure your queue is created like this :

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.queue.my", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

Have this ivar defined in your class (and set it to `FALSE` upon initialization):

```
BOOL _scheduledSearch;
```

Write down this macro at the top of your file (or anywhere really, just make sure its visible)

```
#define SEARCH_DELAY_IN_MS 100
```

And instead of your second snippet, call this method:

```
[self scheduleSearch];
```

Whose implementation is:

```
- (void) scheduleSearch {
    if (_scheduledSearch) return;
    _scheduledSearch = YES;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)((double)SEARCH_DELAY_IN_MS * NSEC_PER_MSEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, myQueue, ^(void){
        _scheduledSearch = NO;
        NSString *searchText = [self textToSearchFor];
        NSArray *tmpArray = [PublicMeathods searchInArray:searchText array:allData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            searchArray = tmpArray;
            [mytable reloadData];
        });
        if (![[self textToSearchFor] isEqualToString:searchText])
            [self scheduleSearch];
    });
}
```

`[self textToSearchFor]` is where you should get the actual search text from.

Here's what it does :

- The first time a request comes in, it sets the `_scheduledSearch` ivar to `TRUE` and tells GCD to schedule a search in 100 ms
- Meanwhile any new search requests is not taken care of, because a search is going to happen anyway in a few ms
- When the scheduled search happens, the `_scheduledSearch` ivar is reset to `FALSE`, so the next request is handled.

You can play with different values for `SEARCH_DELAY_IN_MS` to make it suit your needs. This solution should completely decouple keyboard events with workload generated from the search.

Comment: Thx, but in some cases this will not  work correctly for example if user enter two letters and stop the result will be just for first latter  :(

Comment: there is somethings still wrong the result not allows correct but,I admire in this solution it is the best one until now

Comment: some times when user type in speed way the result will be no correct for example if I type "smithe" the result will be for "smith".
anther issue when user clear up search bar text letter by letter the result will be for first letter in text and some time give me no result in array because calling search method for "" empty string.

Comment: I think the best solution is to stop all search operation until user stop typing after specific time ??? or somethings like that ?

Comment: until now the main problem in this solution is when user clear up search text it will give him a result for last character that he/she delete it.

Comment: I changed the code slightly, I think it should solve the problem you were having.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31254/discussion-between-omarj-and-matehat)

Answer (score 9):

If `searchArray` is the array that is used as table view data source then this array must
only be accessed and modified on the main thread.

Therefore, on the background thread, you should filter into a separate temporary array first. Then you assign the temporary array to `searchArray` on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    NSArray *tmpArray = [PublicMeathods searchInArray:searchText array:allData];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        searchArray = tmpArray;
        [mytable reloadData];
    });
});
```

*Update:* Using a temporary array should solve the crash problem, and using a background thread helps to keep the UI responsive during the search. But as it turned out in the discussion, a major reason for the slow search might be the complicated search logic.

It might help to store additional "normalized" data (e.g. all converted to lower-case, phone numbers converted to a standard form, etc ...) so that the actual search can be done with
faster case-insensitive comparisons.

Comment: but this does not remove the lags :( update my Q. by adding your solu.

Comment: @Omarj: Does it solve the crash problem? - It is difficult to help with the lag. A complicated search might take some time. The advantage of filtering on a background thread is that the UI should stay responsive while the search is active.

Comment: i'm already solve the crash by using the "sync" and it is give me the same result "time&speed" as your answer. so what I search for,a good logic to have the same speed when i use "async" without crash.

Comment: @Omarj: Did you create the `myQueue` with the `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT` flag?

Comment: @Omarj: By default, the queue is *serial*, which means that a filtering process will only start when the previous filtering process has finished. A *concurrent* queue executes the tasks "concurrently". So if you type another letter in a search field, the search will start immediately.

Comment: @Omarj: I don't think that it makes a difference if you use dispatch_async or NSOperationQueue. You have to find the *reason* for the lags first. You can add some NSLog() statements to your methods to find where the time is spent. Or you profile it with Instruments.

Comment: after add NSLog the search method just take 2ms and the reload for data take 30ms.

Comment: so back to the begging i need to split write text operation and reload operation ??
so keyboard will not lags and the reload take the time needed ?

Answer (score 4):

First, a couple notes on the code you presented:

1) It looks as if you're likely queuing up multiple searches as the user types, and these all have to run to completion before the relevant one (the most recent one) updates the display with the desired result set.

2) The second snippet you show is the correct pattern in terms of thread safety.  The first snippet updates the UI before the search completes.  Likely your crash happens with the first snippet because the background thread is updating the searchArray when the main thread is reading from it, meaning that your datasource (backed by searchArray) is in an inconsistent state.

You don't say if you're using a `UISearchDisplayController` or not, and it really doesn't matter.  But if you are, one common issue is not implementing `- (BOOL) searchDisplayController: (UISearchDisplayController *) controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString: (NSString *) filter` and returning NO.  By implementing this method and returning NO you are turning off the default behavior of reloading the tableView with each change to the search term.  Instead you have opportunity to kick off your asynchronous search for the new term, and update the UI (`[tableview reloadData]`) only once you have new results.

Regardless of whether you're using `UISearchDisplayController` you need to take a few things into consideration when implementing your asynchronous search:

1) Ideally you can interrupt a search-in-progress and cancel it if the search is no longer useful (e.g. the search term changed).  Your 'searchInArray' method doesn't appear to support this.  But it's easy to do if your just scanning an array.

1a) If you **can't** cancel your search, you still need a way at the end of the search to see if your results are relevant or not.  If not, then don't update the UI.

2) The search should run on a background thread as to not bog down the main thread and UI.

3) Once the search completes it needs to update the UI (and the UI's datasource) on the main thread.

I put together sample project ([here, on Github](https://github.com/TomSwift/FastFilter)) that performs a pretty inefficient search against a large list of words.  The UI remains responsive as the user types in their term, and the spawned searches cancel themselves as they become irrelevant.  The meat of the sample is this code:

```
- (BOOL) searchDisplayController: (UISearchDisplayController *) controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString: (NSString *) filter
{
    // we'll key off the _currentFilter to know if the search should proceed
    @synchronized (self)
    {
        _currentFilter = [filter copy];
    }

    dispatch_async( _workQueue, ^{

        NSDate* start = [NSDate date];

        // quit before we even begin?
        if ( ![self isCurrentFilter: filter] )
            return;

        // we're going to search, so show the indicator (may already be showing)
        [_activityIndicatorView performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector( startAnimating )
                                                 withObject: nil
                                              waitUntilDone: NO];

        NSMutableArray* filteredWords = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: _allWords.count];

        // only using a NSPredicate here because of the SO question...
        NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", filter];

        // this is a slow search... scan every word using the predicate!
        [_allWords enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            // check if we need to bail every so often:
            if ( idx % 100 == 0 )
            {
                *stop = ![self isCurrentFilter: filter];
                if (*stop)
                {
                    NSTimeInterval ti = [start timeIntervalSinceNow];
                    NSLog( @"interrupted search after %.4lf seconds", -ti);
                    return;
                }
            }

            // check for a match
            if ( [p evaluateWithObject: obj] )
            {
                [filteredWords addObject: obj];
            }
        }];

        // all done - if we're still current then update the UI
        if ( [self isCurrentFilter: filter] )
        {
            NSTimeInterval ti = [start timeIntervalSinceNow];
            NSLog( @"completed search in %.4lf seconds.", -ti);

            dispatch_sync( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                _filteredWords = filteredWords;
                [controller.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
                [_activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
            });
        }
    });

    return FALSE;
}

- (BOOL) isCurrentFilter: (NSString*) filter
{
    @synchronized (self)
    {
        // are we current at this point?
        BOOL current = [_currentFilter isEqualToString: filter];
        return current;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I use just search-bar and use my own UI in this case  can't use - (BOOL) searchDisplayController: (UISearchDisplayController *) controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString: (NSString *) filter;

Comment: @Omarj - same concepts apply.  Likely you want to kick off new searches with each change in input text, and you can get that from the USearchBarDelegate – searchBar:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText: method.

Comment: My result not Always appear in tableView style for example "Grid style".

Answer (score 1):

i believe your crash is indeed solved by the embedding of the display of the UI element for which searchArray is the backing element in a call to GrandCentralDispatch inside of the other call (as you show in your updated original post).  that is the only way to make sure you are not causing the elements of the array to change behind the scenes while the display of the items associated with it is taking place.

however, i believe if you are seeing lag, it is not so much caused by the processing of the array at 2ms or the reload that takes 30ms, but rather by the time it takes GCD to get to the internal dispatch_sync call on the main queue.

if, by this point, you have managed to get the processing of your array down to only 2ms in the worst case (or even if you've managed to get it down to less than 30ms, which is about the time it takes to process a frame in the main run loop at 30 fps), then you should consider abandoning GCD altogether in your effort to process this array.  taking 2ms on the main queue to process your array is not going to cause any buggy behavior.

you may have lag elsewhere (i.e. if you are incrementing search results by trying to go out to the net to get the results, you may want to do the call and then process the response on your separate dispatch queue), but for the times you are talking about, this bit of processing doesn't need to be split out onto separate queues.  for any hard-core processing that takes over 30ms, you should consider GCD.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your functions the next way:

function prototype;

```
- (void)searchInArray:searchText array:allData complete: (void (^)(NSArray *arr)) complete;
```

function itself

```
- (void)searchInArray:searchText array:allData complete: (void (^)(NSArray *arr)) complete { 
    NSArray * array = [NSArray new];
    // function code
    complete(array)//alarming that we have done our stuff
}
```

and when you are calling this function

```
dispatch_queue_t searchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.search",NULL);
dispatch_async(searchQueue,^{
 [PublicMeathods searchInArray:searchText array:allData complete:^(NSArray *arr) {
     searchArray = arr;
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [myTable reloadData];
     });
 }];
});
```

Hope it will help you)

Comment: "dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{" this will freeze the app and block UI :(

Comment: sory i've missprinted now it's Async instead of Sync and it won't freeze the app)

Comment: I already fix it but,no change lags still there when using this solution. :(

Comment: i've changed code a bit. now it's async.  it should work better

Comment: last update not correct u can't make a change on array and UI in async this will make a hole crash :P

Comment: it should work. have you try it? From last update array is changing in background queue and when it's done it returns it in complete block and ONLY THEN it updates table in main queue.

Comment: can you edit your question with adding changes to code which you have done. may be it will simplify search of the solution

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is that `allData` is shared between the main queue and the background queue. If you make a change in `allData` on the main queue, that may shorten `allData` in the background queue, causing an index that used to be valid to become invalid.

It's also possible that the problem is not `allData` itself, but some array within the objects in `allData`. Try setting a breakpoint on exceptions (in Xcode, open the Breakpoints source list, click the plus button at the bottom, and choose "Add Exception Breakpoint...") so you can see exactly where the error occurs.

In either case, you have two possible solutions:

1. Copy the offending object before using it in the search. This protects the background queue from changes in the main queue, but depending on what you need to copy, it may be difficult to get the changes back into the UI—you might have to match the copies back to their originals.
2. Use a lock (like `@synchronized`) or a per-object queue to ensure only one queue is using the object at a time. `NSManagedObjectContext` uses the latter approach for its `-performBlock:` and `-performBlockAndWait:` methods. It may be a little tricky to do this without blocking the main queue, though.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution with the same spirit of the solution presented by Matehad (wait some time and perform a search only if the user doesn't input anything else). Here it is:

Declare 2 global counters and a global string:

int keyboardInterruptionCounter1 = 0, int keyboardInterruptionCounter2 = 0 and NSString *searchTextGlobal

On the searchBar function do this:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

keyboardInterruptionCounter1++;

    searchTextGlobal = searchText;//from local variable to global variable

    NSTimeInterval waitingTimeInSec = 1;//waiting time according to typing speed.

    //waits for the waiting time
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:waitingTimeInSec target:self  selector:@selector(timerSearchBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)timerSearchBar:(NSTimer *)timer{

    keyboardInterruptionCounter2++;

    // enters only if nothing else has been typed.
    if (keyboardInterruptionCounter2 == keyboardInterruptionCounter1) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                             (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {

        //do the search with searchTextGlobal string

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         //update UI
     });

    });

    }
}
```

Explanation: The search is performed only if both counters are the same, this only happens if the user has typed and waited .52 sec without typing anything else. Instead, if the users types fast enough, then no query is done. The solution can be done with or without threading.

Answer (score 0):

Martin R has posted a correct answer. The only thing to point out that instead of

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

it should be

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

The complete code in Swift would be:

```
        let remindersFetcherQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.gmail.hillprincesoftware.remindersplus", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)
        dispatch_sync(remindersFetcherQueue) {
            println("Start background queue")

            estore.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(remindersPredicate) {
                reminders in
                    // var list = ... Do something here with the fetched reminders.
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.list = list   // Assign to a class property
                        self.sendChangedNotification()      // This should send a notification which calls a function to ultimately call setupUI() in your view controller to do all the UI displaying and tableView.reloadData(). 
                    }                        
            }
        }
```

Comment: 3 of the answers are correct :D but we was looking for best one that will give the user good exp.