# Strange objectAtIndex beyond bounds error in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am implementing a search keywords history with predicate in a `UITableView`.

I allocate and init a `NSMutableArray` object `filteredHistory` in viewDidLoad.  This array gets filled when I type something on the search bar (using the `TextDidChange` method in `UISearchBar`).

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchText];
    [self.searchKeywordTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    LogDebug(@"Filtered history count: %d", self.filteredHistory.count);
}
```

I use the method like this to filter:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{
    [self.filteredHistory removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.
    for (MyObject *searchKeyword in self.searchHistory)
    {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                  @"(SELF contains[cd] %@)", searchText];
        [searchKeyword.name compare:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        BOOL resultName = [predicate evaluateWithObject:searchKeyword.name];
        if(resultName)
        {
            [self.filteredHistory addObject:searchKeyword];
        }
    }
}
```

Then reload the `UITableView` in `TextDidChange`.

In `tableView numberOfRowsInSection:` method

```
return self.filteredHistory.count;
```

in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method I have:

```
LogDebug(@"Current row = %d", indexPath.row);
MyObject search = [self.filteredHistory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Then after I tested for a few times the app crashes with an error saying:

```
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'
```

I checked the filteredHistory and the count is 10. Strange thing is in the first few attempts when I typed in the same text in the searchbar there was no problem. In my debug code I could see the count was 10 and the table view displayed the filtered search results from index 0 to 9. I couldn't understand why suddenly the index of filteredHistory is beyond bounds [0..9]? When the code went smoothly, the LogDebug method print out MyObject from index 0 to 9. However when it crashes, it only prints out "Current row = 10".

Comment: Is the filtering done on a background thread by any chance?

Comment: No you can see the filtering is done in the same UIViewController in TextDidChange method of the UISearchBar.

Comment: 1. Is it possible that you have multiple sections in that table?
2. Can you put an `if (indexPath.row > self.filteredHistory.count)` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `NSLog` the `indexPath` there?

Comment: There is only one section. The log message prints out 10 whereas the total count of the filteredHistory array is 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`performSelectorOnMainThread` with `waitUntilDone:NO` here:

```
[self.searchKeywordTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

does not call the method immediately, but later as part of the normal run loop processing.
It could therefore happen that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called *after* you have filtered
the array, but *before* `reloadData` is called.

You should replace that line with an immediate call

```
[self.searchKeywordTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I guess you are right. I tried that and it doesn't crash again. I still have a question because I thought I always need to perform UI changes on main thread and was confused. Every time I reload data I do it on `performSelectorOnMainThread`. Can you tell me when should I use `performSelectorOnMainThread` and when not to use it?

Comment: `textDidChange` is already called on the main thread. Only if you update the UI from a background thread, `performSelectorOnMainThread` (or `dispatch_(a)sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` is needed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16686028/1187415 for a simple example how the filtering can be done on a background thread. The important point is that the data source array must also be updated in the main thread.